# hadoop : write to multiple tables

Tags: hadoop, vertica

I'm trying to write map reduce output to Vertica. At the Job level I can give only 1 table name using DBOutputFormat , But in my case it's a star schema having multiple tables.
Since this is a common case, is there any help already available?
Any pointers will be much helpful.

Comment: Extend DBOutputWritable class and override write() method to do whatever the output you want.

Comment: DBOutputWritable has to be customized for sure .But It's more to do with DBConfiguration class as it can handle only 1 table at a job level.